# How can I import an SSH Key from my iPhone to MacOS?

Tags: macos, ssh-keys

I have created a "Run Script over SSH" shortcut in the Shortcuts app on my iPhone. I have created an SSH Key, and I can get the public and private parts of it.

The Public looks like

ssh-SOMECHARACTERS A-HUGE-BUNCH-OF-CHARACTERS Shortcuts on Almo's iPhone

I'm assuming I need to make some file in ~/.ssh/ on the computer in order to get this to work, but I'm not sure how to proceed on this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the iPhone's public key to the Mac user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file as a new line (or make it the only line if that file doesn't exist yet).

Then the iPhone is authorized to login on the Mac as your user. When you run the shortcut on your iPhone, the specified command should now run on the Mac with the user's permissions. On the first connection, the iPhone will probably complain that it doesn't know the Mac's host key (yet). Once you verified and accepted it, it won't ask you again.